# Onomatopoeia Charades #2

Tags: onomatopoeia-charades

Welcome to installment Number Two.  What object or device makes this sound?:

kIng-FWOOOOOoooooshshshshshshshsh.....

Happy guessing!

---

ANSWER:

The toilet on an airplane.

Comment: Think of how many children's lives have been ruined by being given Onomatopoeia to spell in a spelling bee...

Comment: Even worse if it was a televised one.  On TV for all the world to see how much of a geek you are.

Comment: lol. Ok, now, here's my next idea for this game. To reply, you have to voice it via your microphone, iPhone, MacBook Pro's mic, whatever, to back up why you think it would sound like that. I think we're on to something here.

Comment: #1, Would that still be onomatopoetic? #2, Is onomatopoetic even a word?

Comment: @g.a.harry Yeah! I would think so. It's a chance for someone to show the others why they think it sounds like what is written by performing and demonstrating their logic. :-) Of course it's a word. World leaders have said it.

Comment: Oh yeah?  Who??

Comment: Er, um.. erm....

Answer (score 3):

I think it sounds like... Opening a beer or coke can.

Answer (score 2):

A shovel falling over, handle first, onto the pressure valve of a compressed air tank, breaking it off.

Comment: Oooh, good one.  So much better than the actual answer...

Comment: Thanks. :) (This last part is to fill the character limit.)

Answer (score 2):

I recon you're talking about one of those clay pigeon launchers.
They give a nice "king" sound as they release and the clay pigeons have a FWOOOOOoooooshshshshshshshsh.....
sound as they fly off.

All thats missing is the "BHAROM" of the shotgun going off directly afterwards!  :D

Comment: 'Twas my guess as well!

Answer (score 1):

may be a catapult? XD
or a toilet lol

Answer (score 1):

It's one of those clicking water sprinklers for a lawn,

the sh-sh-sh-sh-sh totally gives it away.

Comment: That would be more like: sh-k sh-k sh-k sh-k shhhhh shikah-shikah-shikah-shikah-shikah-shikah-shikah-shikah-shikah...

Comment: I'm really bad at making it obvious when I'm joking. ;)

Comment: Like I said... no sense of humor?  *This guy*

Comment: ...wait, I mean me.  Damn this internet thing is hard.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the Winklevii of this game (i.e. I had the idea for it and g.a.harry actually made it) and I get 2 guesses on this one:

A garbage disposal starting and cutting up spare food down the sink!

Comment: p.s. I'll see you in court. I'm six-five, 220, on there's two of me.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely needs to become a regular post. Weekly?